# Soap Call in Wordpress Woocommerce PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, soap

I have Soap code which I want to run in wordpress to develop the woocommerce gateway. Here is my PHP code:

```
$cert = dirname(__FILE__) . "/Demo Merchant 2020.pem";
$pass = "Comtrust";
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'verify_peer_name' => true,
        "cafile" => dirname(__FILE__) . "/ca.crt",

        // 'ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA'

    )
);
$options = array(
    'trace' => 1,
    'keep_alive' => true,
    'exceptions' => 0,

    // 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,

    'local_cert' => $cert,
    'passphrase' => $pass,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts) ,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
);
$client = new SoapClient("https://demo-ipg.comtrust.ae:2443/MerchantAPI.svc?singleWsdl", $options);
$params = array(
    'Register' => '',
    'request' => array(
        'Customer' => 'Demo Merchant',
        'Language' => 'en',
        'version' => 2,
        'Amount' => 0.01,
        'Currency' => 'PKR',
        'OrderID' => 1234563434,
        'OrderInfo' => 141850,
        'OrderName' => 141850,
        'ReturnPath' => 'https://soopershop.pk/gateway/finalize.php',
        'TransactionHint' => 'VCC:Y'
    )
);
$result = $client->Register($params);
```

When I call this code alone it works very well but whenever I embed this code in plugin I get this array returned:

https://pastebin.com/gPutXP4v

I am not sure where the problem is. Here is woocommerce code:

https://pastebin.com/GwvJ9B34

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you haven't added a hook to run your code in the loop.

Because you're trying to send the customer order I would recommend running your code on the

```
add_action("woocommerce_order_status_processing", $yourFunction)
```

add this to you plugin.

This will try and run your function after the order has been placed and the customer has paid.